# File files/default/plugins/README does not exist for cookbook ohai

Tags: vagrant, chef-solo

I'm running a provisioning setup using vagrant and chef-solo to install the gitlab cookbook (however, this problem does not seem to be specific to the gitlab cookbook).

The run-list is simple:

```
    {
      "run_list": [
        "recipe[ohai::default]"
      ]
    }
```

The chef-solo run (chef-solo -c solo.rb -j dna.json) results in the following error:

`Error executing action create on resource 'cookbook_file[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins/README]'`

The file IS there:

```
    # ls -l /tmp/vagrant-chef/e939c8a8cabcf9cdd72f5d7c3a98d728/cookbooks/ohai-2.0.1/files/default/plugins/README
        -rwxrwxrwx. 1 vagrant vagrant 49 Oct 21 13:16 /tmp/vagrant-chef/e939c8a8cabcf9cdd72f5d7c3a98d728/cookbooks/ohai-2.0.1/files/default/plugins/README
```

When I check the process with 'strace' it looks like I can see the error source:

```
    10444      0.000210 stat("/tmp/vagrant-chef/cookbooks/cookbooks/ohai/files/default/plugins/README", 0x7ffff0570bb0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

If you notice, the cookbook is named `'ohai-2.0.1'` however the process is trying to access the cookbook `'ohai'` (i.e., without the version number).

Has anyone else encountered this before? I've seen one other post related to the issue that suggested putting `ohai::default` first in the run-list, which I've done (see dna.json above)

Comment: As a test, I created a symbolic link from `ohai-2.0.1` to `ohai` in the `cookbooks` directory and the chef-solo run completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me while using Berkshelf. It names all of the cookbooks `name-version` instead of just `name`. To solve this, I did `berks vendor` and added that directory to my cookbooks path. Now everything works!